# Swift 3 UITableView datasource method viewForHeaderInSection gives warning

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, ios10, xcode8

After migration to Swift 3 I have the following method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {}
```

And it gives me the warning

> Instance method 'tableView(tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:)' nearly
>   matches optional requirement 'tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)'
>   of protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Fix-it offers to make the method private or add @"nonobjc" annotation. How to resolve the warning?

Comment: Running into this problem too. Fix-it also suggested that I mark it private to silence the warning.

Comment: you can not do that, otherwise, this method will not be called

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had similar warnings all over my app. There were 2 problems actually. I fixed all of the warnings either by adding the underscore to the method signature or by moving the method to the right extension which implements the protocol where the method comes from.

I think your problem might be the combination of both.

**In more detail:**

1) You might forget to add the "underscore" character before the "tableView:...", which makes it a different method in Swift 3 (in Swift 2.3 it doesn't matter). So you should change this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

2) The method `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` is from `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, but it looks like the compiler doesn't know about this method–it only knows of the methods from `UITableViewDataSource` and tries to advise you one of them (`tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)`). So you either don't implement `UITableViewDelegate` at all or you do, but in another extension maybe?

Comment: Actually the cause for the issue is that the method was added to datasource extension instead of delegate. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Same for me just added `UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: the 2) hint made it work for me. Amazing how many different "tricks" to silence the warning I read... Just moving the methods into one extension for compliance to UITableViewDataSource and the others into an extension for compliance to UITableViewDelegate fixed it and even made the @obj() decoration obsolete. Thanks.